# replacing showModalDialog in latest chrome version

Tags: google-chrome, window.open, showmodaldialog

I am trying to workaround using showModalDialog for latest chrome versions, regardless the many topics of using window.open instead, I am reading a value from the child dialog to fill a text box in the parent page, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Use my [showModalDialog polyfill](https://github.com/niutech/showModalDialog). It works using either JS generators or eval.

From inside the dialog document, set the `window.returnValue` to any value and upon closing it will be assigned to the `returnValue = showModalDialog(...)`, as with the original `showModalDialog` function.